# this commands in static methods

Tags: c#, forms, class, methods

This is the code.

```
namespace Email
{
    public partial class Form1 : RibbonForm
    {
        //private EventHandler<WriteLogEventArgs> m_pLogCallback = null;
        public static IMAP_Client m_pIMAP = null;

        public Form1()
        {

            m_pConnect_Click();
            //LoadFolders();
            //LoadFolderMessages("Inbox");
            //MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            InitializeComponent();
            InitSkinGallery();
            ribbonControl.SelectedPage = homeRibbonPage1;
        }
        void InitSkinGallery()
        {
            SkinHelper.InitSkinGallery(rgbiSkins, true);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //LoadFolderMessages("Inbox");
        }
        public void m_pImap_Fetch_MessageItems_UntaggedResponse(object sender, EventArgs<IMAP_r_u> e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Value is IMAP_r_u_Fetch)
                {
                    IMAP_r_u_Fetch fetchResp = (IMAP_r_u_Fetch)e.Value;

                    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ListViewItem currentItem = new ListViewItem();
                            currentItem.ImageIndex = 0;
                            currentItem.Tag = fetchResp.UID.UID;

                            string from = "";
                            if (fetchResp.Envelope.From != null)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < fetchResp.Envelope.From.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    if (i == fetchResp.Envelope.From.Length - 1)
                                    {
                                        from += fetchResp.Envelope.From[i].ToString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        from += fetchResp.Envelope.From[i].ToString() + ";";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                from = "<none>";
                            }
                            currentItem.Text = from;

                            currentItem.SubItems.Add(fetchResp.Envelope.Subject != null ? fetchResp.Envelope.Subject : "<none>");

                            currentItem.SubItems.Add(fetchResp.InternalDate.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"));

                            currentItem.SubItems.Add(((decimal)(fetchResp.Rfc822Size.Size / (decimal)1000)).ToString("f2") + " kb");
                            listView1.Items.Insert(0, currentItem);
                        }
                        catch (Exception x)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + x.ToString(), "Error:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + x.ToString(), "Error:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        public static void m_pConnect_Click()
        {
            string m_pUserName = "user@hotmail.com";
            string m_pPassword = "pass";
            string m_pServer = "imap-mail.outlook.com";
            string debug = "";

            IMAP_Client imap = new IMAP_Client();
            try
            {
                imap.Logger = new Logger();
                //imap.Logger.WriteLog += m_pLogCallback;
                imap.Connect(m_pServer, 993, true);

                imap.Login(m_pUserName, m_pPassword);
                m_pIMAP = imap;
                debug = imap.GreetingText;
                //MessageBox.Show(imap.AuthenticatedUserIdentity.Name);

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                debug = x.Message;
                //MessageBox.Show(this, "IMAP server returned: " + x.Message + " !", "Error:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                imap.Dispose();
            }
            //MessageBox.Show(debug);
        }

        public void LoadFolderMessages(string folder)
        {

            IMAP_Client imap = new IMAP_Client();
            imap.Logger = new Logger();
            //imap.Logger.WriteLog += m_pLogCallback;
            imap.Connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", 993, true);
            imap.Login("user@hotmail.com", "pass");
            m_pIMAP = imap;

            //m_pTabPageMail_MessagesToolbar.Items["refresh"].Enabled = true;
            //m_pTabPageMail_Messages.Items.Clear();

            //this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            try
            {
                m_pIMAP.SelectFolder(folder);
                IMAP_Client_SelectedFolder test = m_pIMAP.SelectedFolder;
                int MessagesCount = test.MessagesCount;
                string SeqParse = "0:10";
                string[] parts = SeqParse.Split(':');
                int A = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
                int B = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
                int C = A;
                A = MessagesCount - B;
                B = MessagesCount - C;
                SeqParse = A.ToString() + ":" + B.ToString();

                // Fletching.
                m_pIMAP.Fetch(
                    false,
                    IMAP_t_SeqSet.Parse(SeqParse),
                    new IMAP_t_Fetch_i[]{
                        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Envelope(),
                        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Flags(),
                        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_InternalDate(),
                        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Rfc822Size(),
                        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Uid()
                    },
                    this.m_pImap_Fetch_MessageItems_UntaggedResponse
                );
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + x.ToString());
            }
            //this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

        }

        public void LoadFolders()
        {
            userControl11.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

            TreeNode nodeMain = new TreeNode("IMAP folders");
            nodeMain.Tag = "";
            //userControl11.treeView1.Nodes.Add(nodeMain);
            userControl11.treeView1.Nodes.Add("test");
            userControl11.treeView1.Nodes.Add("test2");

            try
            {
                IMAP_r_u_List[] folders = m_pIMAP.GetFolders(null);

                char folderSeparator = m_pIMAP.FolderSeparator;
                foreach (IMAP_r_u_List folder in folders)
                {
                    string[] folderPath = folder.FolderName.Split(folderSeparator);

                    // Conatins sub folders.
                    if (folderPath.Length > 1)
                    {
                        TreeNodeCollection nodes = nodeMain.Nodes;
                        string currentPath = "";

                        foreach (string fold in folderPath)
                        {
                            if (currentPath.Length > 0)
                            {
                                currentPath += "/" + fold;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                currentPath = fold;
                            }

                            TreeNode node = FindNode(nodes, fold);
                            if (node == null)
                            {
                                node = new TreeNode(fold);
                                node.Tag = currentPath;
                                nodes.Add(node);
                            }

                            nodes = node.Nodes;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(folder.FolderName);
                        node.ImageIndex = 0;
                        node.Tag = folder.FolderName;
                        nodeMain.Nodes.Add(node);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Error:" + x.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            nodeMain.Expand();
        }

        public static TreeNode FindNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string nodeName)
        {
            if (nodes != null)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
                {
                    if (node.Text == nodeName)
                    {
                        return node;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a user control and I want to call the LoadFolderMessages() method from it's class.
However if I do a conversion like this

```
var test = new Form1();
test.LoadFolderMessages("Inbox");
```

doesn't do the trick because Form1() method will run and everything inside it.

Now if I convert the methods into static methods then methods which have this command inside them (this.BeginInvoke...) will throw the exception of the this command being in a static method.

So my question is: How can I call LoadFolderMessages() method from another class?

Comment: Does the user control derive from `RibbonForm` as well?

Comment: No it is a different class. It derives from UserControl.cs if I am understanding correctly your question.

Comment: So anyone has any ideas?